# Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT - driver

Tags: networking, drivers, windows-server-2008-r2

I have got problem with NIC driver. When I go to Device manager, I have got yellow exclamation point there.

[image]

If I uninstall the driver and do Scan for hardware changes, it will freeze the PC and the only solution to unfreeze is hard reset.

[image]

Hardware IDs:

```
    PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_100F&SUBSYS_075015AD&REV_01
    PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_100F&SUBSYS_075015AD
    PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_100F&CC_020000
    PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_100F&CC_0200
```

System Info:

```
    OS Name                          Microsoft windows server 2008 R2 Datacenter 
    version                          6.1.7601 service Pack 1 Build 7601 
    Other OS Description             Not Available 
    OS manufacturer                  Microsoft corporation 
    System Name                      WIN-OSNLGVJODEC 
    System manufacturer              VMware, Inc. 
    System model                     VMware Virtual Platform 
    System Type                      x64-based Pc 
    Processor                        Intel(R) xeon(R) CPU L5640 @ 2.27GHz, 2261 Mhz, 1 core(s)
    BIOS Version/Date                Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 7/30/2013 
    SMBIOS Version                   2.4 
    windows Directory                c:\windows 
    System Directory                 c:\windows\system32 
    Boot Device                      \Device\HarddiskVolume3 
    Locale                           united states 
    Hardware Abstraction Layer       version = "6.1.7601.17514" 
    User Name                        WIN-OSNLGVJODEC\Administrator 
    Time Zone                        Pacific Daylight Time 
    Installed Physical Memory (RAM)  1.00 GB 
    Total Physical memory            1.00 GB 
    Available Physical memory        636 MB 
    Total virtual Memory             2.00 GB 
    Available virtual memory         1.60 GB 
    Page File space                  1.00 GB 
    Page Pile                        c:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: Can you perhaps see what’s listed on the “Driver” tab? Are any of the files missing if you’re looking for them?

Comment: I can find the driver file without any problem. [link](http://s28.postimg.org/458yhy16l/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your System Info says you are using VMware.  Vmware's recommended Network card (NIC) in many/most cases is vmxnet3 (see link below).  To do this:

1) After installing the OS, immediately install VMware tools.

2) Delete the non-vmxnet3 Network adapter in VMware, add new adapter and make it vmxnet3.  That's the recommended NIC. (How-to varies on what version/type of VMware you are using)

Recommended NICs for Windows Server 2008R2

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=Software&productid=11137&vcl=true&supRel=13,24,31,34,71,72,74,76,77,78,79,80,81,85,86,90,148,155,158,162,163,164,165,168,171,172,179,182,187,196,199,201,202,217,218,243,258,259,260,270,271,273,295,301,326,327&testConfig=16

**VMXNET 3: Supported (Recommended) Third generation VMware virtual NIC**

**An example how-to of installing VMware tools**, from http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018377

video - https://youtu.be/tVEw9VprYeQ

1. Ensure that your Windows virtual machine is powered on.
2. Log in to the virtual machine as a user with Administrative privileges.
3. When the desktop is loaded, click **VM** in the virtual machine menu, then click **Guest** > **Install/Upgrade VMware Tools** and click **OK**.
4. The installation wizard appears inside of the virtual machine's console.
   **Note**: If the VMware Tools installation does not start automatically, you may have CDROM Autorun disabled in your Windows environment. To manually run the installation double-click **Computer** and double-click on the CDROM to run it.
5. Follow the prompts in the wizard to complete the VMware Tools installation. Choose the **Typical** installation option.
6. When the VMware Tools installation has finished, restart the virtual machine for the changes to take effect.

**An Example how-to of changing the VMware NIC from anything-else to vmxnet3**

http://www.vmwarebits.com/content/how-to-change-network-adapter-to-vmxnet3-for-windows-guest

Remove the current NIC from Windows first
The best approach is to first remove the NIC that is currently in the virtual machine. If you don't then the adapter's configuration will still be in the Windows-configuration and might conflict with your future networking configuration.

TipFirst make a note of the current IP-configuration so you can use that same configuration for the new adapter. If it is configured with DHCP then it doesn't matter. But be aware that the new vmxnet3-adapter will have a new MAC address so it will not get the same address from your DHCP-server.

To remove the adapter open Device Manager and expand the Network adapters category. Next right-click the Intel adapter and from the menu select Uninstall.

[image]

**Remove the current NIC from the VM and add the VMXNET3-adapter**

​The next step is to remove the current virtual NIC from the virtual machine and add a new NIC of the type VMXNET3.

In the vSphere Web Client browse to your VM and edit the settings. At the bottom of the Edit Settings-screen you see the possibility to add a device. Choose a Network adapter and click Add. Don't forget to open the new adapter's configuration settings to set the type to VMXNET3.

[image]

If you click Ok the new VMXNET3-adapter will be added to your system and be available instantly. At the same time the old adapter will be removed. You can do this while the virtual machine is powered on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It may be a good solution. But unfortunately, i cannot change any settings on vmware including network card. I only have got access to VNC, so i need to make the PRO 1000 MT working. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Intel Pro 1000 MT drivers to your local system, and then using VNC to transfer them?  That would be my next attempt - load new network drivers straight from Intel's installer.  Can you describe why you only have VNC access?  I've only worked in environments where I, or someone I could contact, had access to the VMware administraion tools, so I'm curious.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to install Intel Pro 1000 MT from [Intel drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18720/Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-Server-2008-Final-Release). But it wasn't successful. It says "No Intel(R) Adapters are present in this computer." It's very cheap VPS with VMware Server virtualization. The base variant only have VNC access. Better variants have got access using V-Sphere Client, but it costs about 10 times more.